# Not able to post a Comment

Tags: discussion, bug, comments

I am fairly new to Meta.

[image]

I don't know why i am not able to make a comment even though my comment length is more than 15 character.

Comment: Floris is the OP. The @reply will be removed. So your comment is less than 15 chars....I guess.

Comment: Why to add comments like +1? You can say +1 by upvote.

Comment: Because the `@molot` is kept in that comment, Luv. In the example you give in your post, the @reply would be stripped out. After that stripping out, the comment would not be longer than 15 characters. You can find the details in this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: @Brat Agree. Will keep in mind.

Comment: @Luv off topic... can you please re-upload your profile picture? There was an issue with imgur not resizing pictures correctly in the past that was recently fixed. You can use [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S0KoL.jpg) if you like. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The very sophisticated artificial intelligence behind the minimum character limit correctly determined that your comment does not contain 15 characters worth of actual content.

The `@Floris` is not necessary as the owner of the post is always notified and will be stripped out anyway. A `+1` and a smiley also barely qualify as content ;-)

Comment: **[Why did my this comment got accepted.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7GbQv.png)**

Comment: @Luv, because Mołot is not the questioner, so the @-call remained, so the comment is bigger than 15 characters?

Comment: @Mad Scentist Agree **`:)`**

Comment: That one worked as Mad Scientist is not the insane perfume creator you're trying to contact.